# How to resolve that both Wifi Hotspot and USB Tethering need reboot to work?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wifi-tethering, wifi-hotspot, usb-tethering, networking

I am using a Huawei Honor Device running the official Ice Cream Sandwich. I use the wifi tethering quite often to get my notebook online, and realized following behavior:

- I am connected to Wifi. Everything works fine.
- After a random while, between 15 minutes or 4 hours, the Internet connection times out on my notebook.
- Internet is still working on the device itself though.
- My notebook is shown as connected on the overview list via its MAC Address
- Disabling, enabling Wifi Tethering does not resolve this.
- Only cause of action: reboot the whole phone and then start wifi tethering again.

I am wondering if this is an issue known to multiple Android devices or if this is a hardware issue. If this is software-related, I also am wondering what I could do to resolve this. Factory reset should only be last resort and I am hoping to avoid that.

**UPDATE:** This also happens on USB tethering. This makes me think that the issue is unrelated to either wifi or USB, but resides somewhere in the way Android handles the Internet connection. It *just* suddenly loses connection.

Comment: Just a shot into the blue: As some other WiFi/network connection problems I heard could be worked-around this way, did you try to temporarily switch into airplane mode and back (instead of booting)? I'd not count this a solution either, but if it works, it's still better than a full reboot.

Comment: @Izzy Alas, switching to airplane mode and back didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Sad to hear -- but was worth a try. So another try, which is a little shorter than a full reboot: [Fast Reboot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.greatbytes.fastreboot). Instead of a full reboot, this only restarts the system server -- and should be twice as fast as a full reboot. I bet you would only need to restart a single service, but I cannot say which...

Comment: Does this same issue occur when using either USB or WiFi tethering to other devices, say a different laptop or a second mobile device?

Comment: @Mr.Buster Yes, this issue is not dependent on a specific machine.

Comment: ***Can you provide further details.*** - What is the **notebook** running? (OS, WiFi chip, driver) - Can this problem be corrected at the notebook? (What have you tried?) - What is the root-cause of the **connection timeout**, on the netbook?

Answer (score 1):

I to am using my phone as a 3G modem and sometimes this happens when I messed up some settings in the phone. I just clear the `Settings` data on my phone and it returns to normal.

1. Open `Settings` app
2. Go to `Apps`
3. Go to `ALL` tab
4. find the `Settings` app
5. open it and `Clear Data`
6. try tethering again

this usually fixes the wifi dropping while tethering issue on my xperia play
If your internet keeps timing out while you're connected then it might be also a network issue, or your phone automatically disconnecting from the network due to inactivity. If you frequently take a break using the internet but like to keep the connection alive then I'd recommend using a [pinger](http://www.alsedi.com/pinger.php)